# Using quantifiers with free indices as declarative conditions in equation solving

Tags: equation-solving, logic

This is a toy example:

Is there a way to rewrite

```
Reduce[{Norm@{c[1],  c[2],  c[3]} == 1,
        0 <=  c[1] < c[2] < c[3]},
        {c[1], c[2], c[3]}]
```

As something like

```
Reduce[{Norm@{c[1], c[2], c[3]} == 1,
          0 <= c[1] && 
          ForAll[{i,j}, Implies[i<j, c[i] < c[j]]]}, {c[1], c[2], c[3]}]
```

?
(Which of course doesn't work)

Comment: Can it not be reduced (in most cases) to an equivalent `Table`? For example, `And @@ Flatten@Table[c[i] < c[j], {i, 3}, {j, i + 1, 3}]`... Of course, this is not as elegant as using `ForAll` (if it were possible).

Comment: @rm-rf That's what we always do, and sometimes it's an unwanted burden. Quantifiers let you express any logical proposition (theorem), so a general usage is probably outside the scope of Mma as it is now. But perhaps there is a trick for using them for basic expressions.

Comment: @belisarius I almost certainly missing the point: `Module[{v = {c[1], c[2], c[3]}}, 
 Reduce[{Norm@v == 1, ##, c[1] >= 0}, v] & @@ 
  Thread[Differences[v] > 0]]`

Comment: @ubpdqn The idea is to be able to use logic quantifiers (ForAll, Exists) and FREE indices (i.e. `i , j` vs `1 , 2`) and leave to Mma the building of the necessary "tupling". Your code is off course OK, but now instead of  the used above `"the components of the list are positive and strictly increasing"` for three elements the following `"Each element is equal to at least one multiplication between other two"` with the simplicity of `ForAll[{k}, Exists[{i,j}, i!=j &&i!=k&&j!=k && c[[k]] = c[[i]] c[[j]]]]`